# NodeJs cookie-parser do not save data in cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

I want to create a Login System using NodeJs and React. I want to save in cookie information about the user, such as email, name. I use cookie-parser and do not work. When I try 'res.cookie('name','user.name')' nothing is happend

Here is my code. I have a file named **server.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express();

const user = require('./controller/user.js')
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors())//asta e pt ca UI-ul e pe alt domeniu fata de backend
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.post('/login',user.getLogin)

app.listen(4000, function(){

    console.log("Listening to port 4000")
})
```

and a file **user.js**:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

function getLogin(req, res){


let email = req.body.email
let password = req.body.password


db.collection('user').findOne({email: email, password: password})
.then((user)=>{

    if(user){

        res.cookie("user_email",user.email)
        res.cookie("user_passwordd",user.password)


        return res.json({
            status: 'Users Log in',
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
    }
    else{
            return res.json({
            status: 'Email or password is wrong',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        })
    }
})


}
```

Can you help me a bit?

Comment: _do not work_ is not enough to help you. Make sure to elaborate more on what doesn't work, and include any sort of errors/exceptions you have encountered.

Comment: When I try console.log(req.cookies.user_email) the result is 'undefine', this is the problem. user_email is ok, is provide from req.body.email, problem is from cookie-parser.

Comment: How are you calling POST /login and where from?

Comment: In the file server.js, app.post('/login',user.getLogin) and getLogin function is from the user.js file

Comment: I try something like: res.cookie('name','everything'), but req.cookies.name is still undefine, this is the reason when I say the cookie do not work

Comment: I received a hint: I use cors, because I use ReactJs and my UI is on a different domain than the backend. How can I solve the conflic between cors and cookie-parser?

Comment: @PopaLaris did you find solution?

Comment: Yes, it is ok! :)

Comment: @PopaLaris what the solution?

Comment: @AdirZoari it was something with cors.